# Telegram API sporadically throws SSL-related exceptions on requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, telegram-api

Our clients started to complain about undelivered messages when using Telegram API in our app. The strangest thing is that errors appear sporadically. The problem **may occur spontaneously and then disappear** after awhile (15-30min), and then everything is fine for several hours (or even days / weeks).

Telegram gives such errors:

1. `SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)` - appears 98% of the time
2. `SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",)` - appears 1% of the time
3. `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))` - appears 1% of the time

I tried to reproduce SSL errors on our test server: the first error appeared only once in 30 minutes of me "spamming messages" every few seconds.

I checked related SO questions. Some people were complaining about unsupported ciphers, so I checked our SSL:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

Also I did not find any recent changes in Telegram API which may be an issue.

Our venv (python2.7):

```
requests==2.13.0
pyopenssl==19.1.0
cryptography==3.2.1
idna==2.10
```

Right now (22.06) I checked logs and everything seems to be fine. Can it be a Telegram-side issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a week since the last error (all our services are working as expected), so it's Telegram-side issues for sure.